# Firefox has lag displaying jQuery animate on page load

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

http://www.jeremyschultz.com/client/boa/WBR/

On page load, the initial slide (and subsequent slides when viewed) should generate and animate a bar chart. Charts start from the x-axis and the bar heights are animated with jQuery animate().

This appears to work fine in Chrome and Safari but Firefox has a lag of almost 2 seconds on page load so the first slide (which calls animate() when DOM is ready) does not show most of the animation.

I'm not sure what the cause or the best solution would be so I'm listing it here for input.

Comment: if you ask questions you should supply some code details here in the question. the questions you ask should also help other people, but your link could go away. the _only_ problem i see is that your code relies on a fully loaded and applied stylesheet and the animation starts sometimes before the stylesheet is loaded/applied, so the animation does not work correctly (bars sliding down instead up).

Comment: Works straight away on my Firefox (OSX 10.7, Firefox 14), for the record.

Comment: Sorry, I figured readers could check the source and see the script: http://www.jeremyschultz.com/client/boa/WBR/js/scripts.js

Thanks for the feedback re: posting. Sounds like these issues are more about slow page load than browser/code bugs.